# Sprite is slowing as it approaches touch point

Tags: sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit, and my sprite is slowing as it approaches the touched point.

I would like the sprite to remain at a fixed speed as it moved from initial point to the touched point on the screen.

Currently, i have the duration set to 3.0

In the touchesEnded event, i gather the new point of the touch and save the value to a property.

In the scene update event, i perform a

```
float realMoveDuration = 3.0;
SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveTo:self.newPoint duration:realMoveDuration];
[self.player runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove]]];
```

So when the player sprite starts getting closer to the touch point, the movement slows down, and gradually reaches the touch point.

This is not the action I am looking for, i would like the player sprite to continue at a constant rate of travel to the touched point.

Comment: more context and code, please

Comment: You say in the scene update you run that action. Are you running that action every frame ? If so, that's likely your problem as you are adding a new action 60 times a second. Also, having a sequence is not needed if you only have one action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just run your SKAction in the touchesEnded event.

If you have that code in the update event, it's starting a new SKAction 60 times per second. You only ever need to run a new SKAction when there is a change in destination.

If there is a change in destination before you reach the original destination, you should remove the action from that node and then add a new one.

Also, not certain about the specifics of what you are doing, but how quickly an object moves is based on the distance and the time you have specified for it to get there. So if you want a node to move at a consistent speed, regardless of distance, you need to make a calculation to determine the right duration to set for your SKAction.

For example if speed represents pixels/units per second you might do this to calculate your duration :

```
duration = distance / speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an SKAction to move the sprite, use the `timingMode` property. The default is `SKActionTimingLinear`. So if you haven't changed it, the node should move at a constant speed.

Here's a link to the available [Action Timing Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SKActionTimingMode).

Comment: Yes, i have not modified the timingMode property, so linear should still be in effect...  perhaps i am putting the SKAction in the wrong event?  but i am also having the same issue when i put the code in the touchesEnded event

Comment: You shouldn't put that `SKAction` in the update method. What happens: On every update ( = 60 times per second) the `SKAction` is called and the player moves towards the newPoint. Since the distance becomes smaller every time, but the realMoveDuration stays 3 seconds, the speed gradually decreases and the movement slows down.